# Sprockets::CircularDependencyError in Store#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sprockets

**I am following the manual Agile Web Development with Rails 4th edition and I have a problem with sprocket css in rails 3.1.**

The code css is:

http://media.pragprog.com/titles/rails4/code/rails31/depot_e/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss

**If I modify the css code of app/assets/stylesheets/aplication.css.scss I catch the next error:**

```
Sprockets::CircularDependencyError in Store#index

Showing /home/ubuntu/Desktop/Depot/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #5 raised:

/home/ubuntu/Desktop/Depot/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss has already been required
Extracted source (around line #5):

2: <html>
3: <head>
4:   <title>Pragprog Books Online Store</title>
5: <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>
6: <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
7: <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
8: </head>
Rails.root: /home/ubuntu/Desktop/Depot

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:5:in`_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___1008723970_81658620'
```

I dont understand why if I modify a margin value or a padding value in aplication.css.scss for example I get this error.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Does it go away when you restart your server?

Comment: Not. I have restart the server but the problem is not fixed. If I desactive the css the page working but without css. I have removed from aplication.html.erb the <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>. Then The page working fine but without css. I dont know that I can doing for fixed this problem :(. Thank you very much.

Comment: Please put up a reproducible example.

Comment: can you post the contents of the application.css file please?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You should remove app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.

Comment: this is called quick fix ;)

Comment: Yeah, `require_tree .` means "require everything in this directory and all children" and is in the generated `application.css`. Pretty weird that by default Rails says "include all CSS in all pages always", huh?

Answer (score 14):

I had a similar problem:
[Asset pipeline not precompiling sass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8803226/asset-pipeline-not-precompiling-sass)

The circular dependency happens when the manifest file requires the tree files. Sass does this anyway so it's not necessary.

Remove:

```
 *= require_tree .
```

Comment: Why the hell isn't this documented as such. Coming from .NET this is very confusing. I have to google for pretty much everything. :/

Comment: Asset pipeline is pretty new and confusing to a lot of people. It will get easier :)

Comment: Greate yar, You have saved my lots of time.

Answer (score 2):

I was having this same problem after installing SCSS. I fixed the problem by removing the defult comments that rails places in the header. So this:

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
 * compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
*/

#wrapper {
    width: 980px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Became this:

```
#wrapper {
    width: 980px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Those "default comments" are called "directives" and without them, you will have to explicitly include and precompile your asset CSS files. Which might be OK for you but is not standard Rails these days.

Comment: Correct. This was a couple of years ago I was having this issue. I'm not anymore and everything is working as expected. I'm pretty sure my problem was something I was doing wrong at the time.

Answer (score 0):

Just name the application.css as "application.scss". This will solve your problem.