# Asset pipeline not precompiling sass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sass, asset-pipeline

I've updated my app to use the rails 3.1 asset pipeline (I think). I can compile .css files but not css.scss. I am running the sass-rails gem but nothing seems to work.

What should I check? Sorry, I don't know exactly what info I should supply here to help debug. I can edit this...

EDITS:

My .scss file contains:

```
/*
*= require_self
*= require_tree . 
*/
```

edit:
see [Sprockets::CircularDependencyError in Store#index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462661/sprocketscirculardependencyerror-in-storeindex/8813029#8813029)

Thanks,
Rim

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that css.scss files need to be included, not imported like the rest:

So: Turn you application.css into an application.css.scss, and do like this in it:

```
/*
*= require ./normal/custom.css
*= require_self
*/

@import "normal/design/control_panel";
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Yes, that seems right. I'll edit my question.

Comment: I removed  *= require_tree . which was causing some circular dependency issues.

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462661/sprocketscirculardependencyerror-in-storeindex/8813029#8813029

Comment: Not exactly... you should `@import "normal/design/control_panel"` (no file extension). And yeah, `require_tree` means `require everything in this directory and all children`. Pretty weird that by default Rails says "include all CSS in all pages always", huh?